# Clear Icon along with loading Icon on PrimeNG Autocomplete

Tags: css, autocomplete, primeng

I would like to customize the X icon on the p-autocomplete component, in order to get this:

**Loading suggestions phase:**

[image]

**Done loading suggestions:**

[image]

The only thing that i'm getting right now is this:

[image]

The X icon doesn't move to the right, even if the primeng loading icon is not visible.
The only thing i was able to achieve was this:

[image]

```
input[type="search"] {
  padding-right:0px!important;
}
```

I know that i can customize the X icon by using

```
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  ...
}
```

But i don't know how.
Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

This is how you achieve to show the X icon:

```
<p-autocomplete ... [type]="'search'"></p-autocomplete>
```

Comment: how did you inserted the loading icon ?

Comment: It's already in the p-autocomplete component, i didn't have to do anything.

Comment: Can you share your HTML code please ? I can't see the close button while using Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: Edited the question. @Antikhippe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this to your CSS :

```
i.ui-autocomplete-loader {
  margin: -44px;
}
```

**Result**

[image]

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2uca1f)

Comment: Ok, not sure why but your solution was ok in the StackBlitz but not in my app. Neverthless, it suggested me to do this: input[type="search"] {
  padding-right:5px!important;
}

.ui-autocomplete-loader {
  margin-right: 20px;
} it worked just fine in this way ; ) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```css
::ng-deep .p-autocomplete-loader {
    margin-right: 20px !important;
}
```